# Pandas convert column with missing values with counts into distributions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame like this:

```
  df = 

        A             B                  C
        A1            B1                 20
        A1            B2                 4
        A1            B3                 1
        A2            B2                 6
        A3            ...              ...
        ...           ...               ...
```

For a fixed set of values of B = [B1, B2, B3], I want to convert C into distribution

Desired Output =

```
       A              B                  C
       A1            [B1 B2 B3]          [0.8 0.16 0.04]
       A2            [B1 B2 B3]          [0.0 1.0   0.0]
       A3            [B1 B2 B3]           ...
```

How to handle missing values in every group for B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), filter columns `B`, divide by `sum` and last create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
B = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']

df = df.pivot('A','B','C')[B].fillna(0)
df1 = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':df1.index, 'B':[B] * len(df1), 'C': df1.to_numpy().tolist()})
print (df2)
    A             B                  C
0  A1  [B1, B2, B3]  [0.8, 0.16, 0.04]
1  A2  [B1, B2, B3]    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```